# Scratch - How to stop the program, but not exterminate

Tags: mit-scratch

How do I halt the program while the question isn't answered (collision with stars)?
I've tried the *stop all* block from *control*, but it exterminates the program.
[Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/351832494/editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is having a similar problem, I was able to resolve it by initializing a variable which I set to 0. If an event occurred and I needed to halt the game, I set the aforementioned variable to 1. For example in one of my Star sprites:
[image]

In my Rock sprite, I am checking every loop for that variable, if that value is 0, than the code can keep on executing.
[image]